# Go Back in Angular 6 when skiplocationchange is true

Tags: javascript, html, angular, routes, angular6

**Routing in Angular 6**

When i route to a particular location i navigate with

```
route.navigate(['/home'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

but when returning back to previous route the below code is not helping,
Is there any another way or should by remove "{ skipLocationChange: true }"

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  // component's declarations here
})
class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private _location: Location) 
  {}

  backClicked() {
    this._location.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found how to hide url and at the same time be able to go back in Angular? I need it too. :)

Comment: No @YaroslavTrofimov I wrote a service which saves my url history and push and pop base on Forward and Backward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`skipLocationChange`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#skipLocationChange)

> Navigates without pushing a new state into history.

This is why using `location.back()` will not work as it simply moves the browser back to the previous state in the history. And the current state is unchanged even though the url in the browser was modified.

You should not use `skipLocationChange` if you want the next state of the page to be added to the browser's history.

Comment: Is There any other way to hide my url

Answer (score 1):

you can pass dynamic data to a Route
The option to pass the dynamic data or a user-defined object was added in the
Angular Version +8 using the state object. The state object is stored in History API

Using routerLink directive

```
<a [routerLink]="['antherUrl']" [state]="{ id:1 , name:'currentUrl'}">Dynamic Data</a>
```

Using navigateByUrl

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/antherUrl', { state: { id:1 , name:'currentUrl' } });
```

Accessing the state value
The state can be accessed by using the **getCurrentNavigation** method of the router (works only in the constructor)

```
 perviousUrl = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state


goBack() {
 this.router.navigate([this.previousUrl.name],{skipLocationChange: true});
}
```